# How to achieve an angular butterbar effect in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation

We are looking to achieve something like a "butterbar", which is basically a UIView that changes color from the middle outwards to the edges.  An example is this [codepen](https://codepen.io/wangchuan/pen/rLNoBx) .

```
How to do this in swift?
```

Comment: seems your link is broken

Comment: Please show what research you've undertaken, what you've already tried, code samples etc. Read [ask] and [mcve] and update your question.

Comment: However, it was an interesting problem to solve. So much as I hate to reward this kind of question…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution for you. Basically, there's a `ButterBar` `UIView` subclass, that has an inner view subview, and an array of colours.

- Set the background to colour[0]
- Set the inner background to colour[1]
- Set the inner width to 0
- Animate the inner width to the `ButterBar` width
- Set the background colour to the inner background colour
- Set the inner background to the next colour
- Repeat

Code…

```
class ButterBar: UIView {

    private let innerView = UIView(frame: .zero)
    private var colours: [UIColor] = [.black, .white]
    private var colourIndex = 0
    private var isAnimating = false
    private lazy var widthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = {
        return innerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configure()
    }

    func configure(colours: [UIColor]) {
        guard colours.count > 1 else { return }
        self.colours = colours
    }

    func startAnimating() {
        colourIndex = 0
        isAnimating = true
        updateColours()
        animate()
    }

    func stopAnimating() {
        isAnimating = false
    }
}

private extension ButterBar {

    func configure() {
         innerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(innerView)
        topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: innerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: innerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: innerView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        widthConstraint.isActive = true
    }

    func updateColours() {
        backgroundColor = colours[colourIndex]
        colourIndex = (colourIndex + 1) % colours.count
        innerView.backgroundColor = colours[colourIndex]
    }

    func animate() {
        widthConstraint.constant = 0
        layoutIfNeeded()

        widthConstraint.constant = bounds.width
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }) { _ in
            if self.isAnimating {
                self.updateColours()
                self.animate()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And…

```
@IBOutlet weak var butterBar: ButterBar!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    butterBar.configure(colours: [.red, .blue, .green, .yellow])
    butterBar.startAnimating()
}
```

Comment: Just a question: Why did you choose to have an extension and not just include the functions in the private extension in the class itself?

Comment: It's a personal preference - I tend to put all private methods in a private extension

Answer (score 1):

You could use two UIViews that are constrained to the center of the parent and possess width constraints. Simply set the background color of the first view and animate its width constraint from 0 to the width of the parent. Once this is done, you can bring the other view to front and animate its width from 0 to the width of the parent, then restart with the initial view to keep the cycle going.